# Can I query a role with an ActiveRecord where using Rolify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rolify

I'm using [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) for roles in my rails application. I know I can query roles with `user.has_role?(:admin)`. But I need to be able to query roles with a `where` clause:

```
User.where(age: 25..35, role: :manager)
```

Is there a way Rolify supports this? My thoughts are, maybe I need to create an ActiveRecord model for the `roles` table Rolify creates. Or maybe Rolify has a mechanism like above? Or maybe the best thing is for me to do away with Rolify and have a similar mechanism, but with an ActiveRecord model instead.

Comment: The answer is in the documentation you linked : https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#class-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into [docs](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#class-level):

```
User.with_role(:manager).where(age: 25..35)
```

Comment: So that will result in a single query to my database? This is great.

Comment: @at. yea, it is likely to be a single query

Comment: just tested, it is 1 query!